# dependency property registered in generic base class

Tags: wpf, controls, dependency-properties

I am trying to construct a validating textbox control using a generic abstract base class as follows and register Min and Max value properites:

```
public abstract class ValidatingTextBoxBase<T, C> 
    : TextBox where T : Icomparable<T>


public static readonly DependencyProperty MinValueProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("MinValue", typeof(T), typeof(C), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DefaultMinValue));

    public T MinValue
    {
        get { return (T)GetValue(MinValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinValueProperty, value); }
    }
```

Then I declare several text box controls:

```
public class IntegerTextBox : ValidatingTextBoxBase<int, IntegerTextBox>
{

public class DecimalTextBox : ValidatingTextBoxBase<decimal, DecimalTextBox>
    {
```

At runtime this works great however I get a lot of design time errors for

```
'MinValue' property was already registered by 'DecimalTextBox'
```

or it will be IntegerTextBox or one of the others depending on which view is open.

Any thoughts/help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce the design-time error. It's working fine for me. Where are you defining `DecimalTextBox` etc.?

Comment: The class definitions are just in the same namespace as the base class.  The instances are defined in various UserControls (in XAML) and Windows (in XAML) in the application.

Comment: I don't know what to say. The exception indicates that `DependencyProperty.Register` is getting called twice with the same first and third parameters. One explanation could be redundant class definitions in different namespaces. I wonder though if it's a XAML designer bug. You must have done a clean build and restarted VS?

Comment: Yeah, and we are seeing it with multiple developers using it.  I worked around it for now by making the property abstract and moving the dependency property declarations into the derivative classes.  Not as clean but functional until I have time to figure it out.  Thanks for the effort.

Comment: That's a lot better than nothing. Can you put together an example that reproduces reliably?

Comment: How did you create the abstract DependencyProperty?